# Avoiding global onBeforeAction methods on a server side route

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a server-side route that I use for Facebook share (since it requires a URL nowadays)

```
this.route('share',{
    path: '/share',
    where: 'server'
}).get(function(data){
    var query = data.query;

    this.response.write('<html>');
    this.response.write('<head>');
    // content type is text/html by default
    this.response.write('<title></title>');

    if(query){
        for(var prop in query){
            if(query.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                this.response.write('<meta property="'+prop+'" content="'+query[prop]+'" />');
            }
        }
    }

    this.response.write('</head>');
    this.response.write('<body></body>');
    this.response.write('</html>');

    this.response.end();
});
```

But my global `Router.onBeforeAction()` function still gets called, which uses jQuery (animation) -- this causes problems on the server side.

Is there a way to skip over global hooks or should I just check if jQuery is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [iron:router guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#applying-hooks-to-specific-routes), you should declare your global onBeforeAction hook using the except option :

```
Router.onBeforeAction(yourGlobalHook, {
  except: ['share']
});
```